# unity build crashes on loadscene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

am trying to run my unity build but it crashes when i try to change the scene and sometimes it crashes
when i start the build , but i have no error it works fine in the editor
here is the error log file :

i checked the Don't destroyOnLoad function but it was not the reason of the crash

```
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/TexturesD3D11.cpp Line: 406)

d3d11: failed to create 2D texture id=362 width=2048 height=451 mips=1 dxgifmt=28 [D3D error was 
887a0005]


(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/TexturesD3D11.cpp Line: 442)

 d3d11: failed to create 2D texture shader resource view id=362 [D3D error was 80070057]


 (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/TexturesD3D11.cpp Line: 406)

  D3D shader create error for vertex shader [0x887a0005]
  D3D shader create error for pixel shader [0x887a0005]
  D3D shader create error for vertex shader [0x887a0005]
  D3D shader create error for pixel shader [0x887a0005]
  d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x1 mode 0 size 1123248) [0x887A0005]
  d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x1 mode 0 size 3144) [0x887A0005]
  d3d11: failed to create buffer (target 0x2 mode 0 size 516) [0x887A0005]
  d3d11: failed to create 2D texture id=242 width=256 height=256 mips=1 dxgifmt=65 [D3D error was 
  887a0005]


  (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/TexturesD3D11.cpp Line: 442)

  d3d11: failed to create 2D texture shader resource view id=242 [D3D error was 80070057]


  (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/GfxDevice/d3d11/TexturesD3D11.cpp Line: 406)

   The referenced script (Vuforia.GuideViewCameraBehaviour) on this Behaviour is missing!

  (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Scripting/ManagedReference/SerializableManagedRef.cpp 
  Line: 197)

   Crash!!!
  The referenced script (Vuforia.GuideViewCameraBehaviour) on this Behaviour is missing!

  (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Scripting/ManagedReference/SerializableManagedRef.cpp 
      Line: 197)

      The referenced script (Vuforia.GuideViewCameraBehaviour) on this Behaviour is missing!

   (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Scripting/ManagedReference/SerializableManagedRef.cpp 
    Line: 197)

   SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;D:\Covid- 
   1984\Wayfinding;D:\Covid1984\Wayfinding;C:\
    Windows;C:\Windows\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;',
   symOptions: 534, UserName: 'No'
   OS-Version: 6.1.0
   D:\Covid-1984\Wayfinding\Wayfinding.exe:Wayfinding.exe (000000013F960000), size: 667648 (result: 
   0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2019.1.7.50322
   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (00000000771A0000), size: 1699840 (result: 0), SymType: '- 
   deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.24475
   The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'STAND') is missing!

   (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/ManagedMonoBehaviourRef.cpp Line: 333)

   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll:kernel32.dll (0000000077080000), size: 1175552 (result: 0), 
   SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.24475
   The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'TAPIS ROUGE') is missing!

   (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/ManagedMonoBehaviourRef.cpp Line: 333)

   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (000007FEFCDF0000), size: 421888 (result: 0), 
    SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.24475
   The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'O'KAWA') is missing!

   C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll:credssp.dll (000007FEFC0E0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: 
   '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.24475
   C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll:rasadhlp.dll (000007FEF69E0000), size: 32768 (result: 0), 
   SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385


         ========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================

     0x000007FEFAF32D72 (d3d11) D3DKMTCloseAdapter
     0x000007FEC56F1BEB (UnityPlayer) TexturesD3D11::UploadTextureSubData2D
     0x000007FEC56EA24F (UnityPlayer) GfxDeviceD3D11Base::UploadTextureSubData2D
     0x000007FEC575218F (UnityPlayer) GfxDeviceWorker::RunCommand
     0x000007FEC5757F9B (UnityPlayer) GfxDeviceWorker::RunExt
     0x000007FEC5758095 (UnityPlayer) GfxDeviceWorker::RunGfxDeviceWorker
     0x000007FEC5F29424 (UnityPlayer) Thread::RunThreadWrapper
     0x000000007709556D (kernel32) BaseThreadInitThunk
     0x00000000771F385D (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

        ========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
```

please help!
i saw lot of suggested solutions but nothing works for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: `The referenced script on this Behaviour  is missing` this sounds like some of your components are missing. Might happen e.g. if the DLL containing them is not compatible with the target platform you are building for ... Did you also see [Direct3D Error Code 80070057](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/direct3d-error-code-80070057)?

Comment: i debugged the game and it leaves this error                                                     
     d3d11.dll caused an Access Violation                                                                          i run it as administrator but nothing changes

Comment: an Access Vilation can also mean that a file is e.g. opened in another program or you are trying to open two streams on it at the same time ...